# Headset undetected when plugged in

Tags: pulseaudio, headphones, speakers, audio-jack

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 in my machine which was running windows 7. I have been trying to configure the audio to work exactly as it used to work in Windows but never been able to do so. I have followed [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96367/how-can-i-get-line-in-microphone-working-with-skype-on-lubuntu-11-10) exactly. I am still not getting the required configuration. `aslamixer` command shows me with 5 adjustable controls as shown below

```
1. Master        "adjustable"
2. Speaker       "adjustable"
3. PCM           "adjustable"  
4. Front         "adjustable"           AND
5. Beep          "adjustable"  
6. Mic Jack      Mic In or Lin In
7. S/PDIF    OO   "in a box"
8. S/PDIF D  OO     "in a box"
9. S/PDIF P  DIGITAL or Analog M
```

It does not detect the headset jack when plugged in. I here mean to say that the sound form the speakers does not go off when I plug in my headset jack. How can I make this working. Some other googling also did not help. I am on Hp Pavilion DV7 machine. The chip is IDT 92HD75B3X5 and the card is HDA ATI SB.

Edit: `aplay -l` gives the following output, I do have the inbuilt mic.

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1   
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: STAC92xx Digital [STAC92xx Digital]  
  Subdevices: 1/1   
  Subdevice #0: subdevice#0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]  
  Subdevices: 1/1   >
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: The question you have followed is specific for Lubuntu, which doesn't have pulseaudio pre-install. Ubuntu has pulseaudio by default, and what you really should be searching for is `jack sensing`. If you want help, please post the output of `aplay -l` as is. Also, is there a built in mic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/580233) with exactly the same problem as well as audio devices. It's not a fix, but rather a workaround, but it seems to have worked for at least two users with HP's DV6s.

To try the workaround, open a terminal window (ctrl-alt-t), and copy/paste the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

...then add the following lines to the bottom of the file, save and exit.

```
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m4-1 enable_msi=1
```

To test, either reboot, or run `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it fixed my pain of a.. you deserve more than kudos.

Comment: Glad that worked for you.

Comment: Worked for Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 16.04. Thank you!

Comment: any work around for 19.04 ?

Comment: Headset not detecting was only a one-time thing for me (normally fine) and `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` on it's own was enouhg to fix it.