# Ubuntu 18.04 Not detect headset after restart

Tags: bug-reporting

Every time the Computer restart I need to unplug and replug,
I try this solution not work: [Headset undetected when plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184901/headset-undetected-when-plugged-in)