# How to use alsamixer for line in microphone input?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, input

I'm new hear and I am trying to get my computer to work with a microphone for input audio. I am using the line in 3.5 mm jack for the microphone, not a usb. I am using Xubuntu version 12 on a desktop computer, and also I am using Ubuntu v 12 in my Oracle VBox virtual machine. Neither work with input audio, for example I can not even get skype to get the input audio. I just installed pulse audio as well. For my virtual machine, It is on my laptop (Dell Inspirion) and I am just trying to use the built in mic, so this may be a different issue altogether and I may make a separate thread for that. Anyways, I have found a post on this forum [How can I get line-in microphone working with Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96367/how-can-i-get-line-in-microphone-working-with-skype) that is an example of using alsamixer to set the setting, I'm assuming in the terminal. So I run alsamixer and it opens up the controls, but it's not quite clear and doesn't seem to match what is in the post that is linked here. For instance, it says for output set these values:
- Line-in: 40
- Mic: 63
- Phone: 40
- Aux: 40
- Analog Source: mic
- Digital Source: i2s in
- Shared Mic: mic in

I am not sure which items these correspond to in the terminal screen, I see:
 -Master, Master H, Headphone, Headphone, PCM, Line, Line Jack, CD, MIC, Phone, S/PDIF, S/PDIF P, AUX, External, Stereo M, a few others but I dont see Digital Source, Shared Mi, Analog Source...I dont see where it has Input settings and Output settings either, maybe I am missing something?
They have bars that can go up or down to set the values. Any advice on what I should be doing to get this to work? I did the troubleshooting stuff and it is recognizing my sound card, and it is compatible, and it will play back a sample wav using "aplay .../Front_Center.wav". Thanks for any help!